# In △ABC, BD : DC = CE : EA = AF : FB = 1:4. Let K, L and M are points of intersection of AD, BE and CF, as shown on the picture...

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In $\triangle ABC$, $BD:DC = CE : EA = AF : FB = 1:4$. Let $K$, $L$ and $M$ are points of intersection of $AD$, $BE$ and $CF$, as shown on the picture. Suppose the area of $\triangle ABC$ is 1, find the area of $\triangle KLM$.
[image]

Comment: There is a more general theorem when the sides are all divided in the same ratio. Can't remember the name. In math, as in magic, knowing names gives you power.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. It is Routh's theorem.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%27s_theorem